# Como puedo quitar el link en mi pdf al imprimirlo desde mi html

Tags: html, pdf

tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo en mi HTML un reporte en php, al momento de imprimirlo con Ctrl+p sale un link en mi PDF en la parte inferior y en la parte superior.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese link me aparece tal cual tanto arriba como al final del PDF.

Como puedo hacer para que al presionar las teclas Ctrl+p en mi html lo pueda imprimir sin esos link.

Quedo atento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas en Chrome, cuando te sale el dialogo de impresión, fijate que dice mas ajustes y al fondo una de las opciones es un checkbox "Encabezado y pie de pagina", tenes que sacar ese tilde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: perfecto me funciono como quería, muchas gracias.